# Gradle maven-publish library with dependence on module with multiple publications

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I have a library I'm trying to publish that has a dependency on another module in the same project with multiple publications as well. If I configure the gradle build files like this I run into an error.

**build.gradle**(Module:transaction-manager)

```kotlin
dependencies {
    api project(':library')
}



afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId "com.example.sdk"
                artifactId "transaction-manager"
                version "1.0.0"
            }
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                from components.debug
                groupId "com.example.sdk"
                artifactId "transaction-manager-debug"
                version "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**(Module:library)

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId "com.example.sdk"
                artifactId "core"
                version "1.0.0"
            }
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                from components.debug
                groupId "com.example.sdk"
                artifactId "core-debug"
                version "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
> Publishing is not able to resolve a dependency on a project with multiple publications that have different coordinates.
  Found the following publications in project ':library':
    - Maven publication 'release' with coordinates com.example.sdk:core:1.0.0
    - Maven publication 'debug' with coordinates com.example.sdk:core-debug:1.0.0
```

if I configure the gradle build like this I'm able to build with no issue.

**build.gradle**(Module:transaction-manager)

```kotlin
dependencies {
    debugApi 'com.example.sdk:core-debug:1.+'
    releaseApi 'com.example.sdk:core:1.+'
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId "com.example.sdk"
                artifactId "transaction-manager"
                version "1.0.0"
            }
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                from components.debug
                groupId "com.example.sdk"
                artifactId "transaction-manager-debug"
                version "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that I have to build the core library first before I can build the transaction manager. I was wondering if there was a way for me to keep the transaction module pointing to the library with **api project(':library')** and specify which publication I want to use?

Comment: did you find a solution to this one?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solution ?